# Display BloB picture Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig, blob

How I can display a BloB picture saved in BD with symfony2 and twig.

Help PLZ.

My entity image :

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="img", type="blob", nullable=false)
 */
private $img;

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $titre;

/**
 * 
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 * 
 */
private $file;
```

i would like to display the picture without creat a Directory to apload the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define new route and controller for retrieving image. Something like this:

```
# routing.yml
my_image_route:
    pattern: /images/{id}
    defaults: {_controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:some}
```

and controller:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function someAction($id)
    {    
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $image_obj = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Image')->find($id);
        return new Response(
            $image_obj->getImg(),
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            array('content-type' => 'image/jpeg');
        }
}
```

and in template simply generate this route

```
{{ path('my_image_route', {'id': image.id}) }}
```

Comment: I have this error : 
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class